# How to create object array arr[{},{}] format dynamically in Angular2

Tags: typescript

I know this is silly question but I unable to do it. I declare variable arr=[]; and i'm pushing object value dynamically. But no luck.
I want array in following format

```
arr[
   {name:"abc"},
   {name:"pqr"}
];
```

But I unable to get in above format.
My code is:

```
var arr= [];
for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  let lg= {
  name:list[i]
};
arr.push(lg);
}
```

Where i'm doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: What is `list` and `log`??

Comment: @developer033, Thank you for response. list is array and its contains only string.

Comment: @Julien, Thank you for response. By mistake I wrote log.push() at the time of writing question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

assume you have `list` array,

```
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { //be careful about array length, and index maybe start from zero
  let lg = {
    name: list[i]
  };
  arr.push(lg); // not log
}
```

code demo here: http://jsbin.com/xazihekuti/edit?js,console

Comment: @AnilJagtap, if two answers are exactly the same, it's usually polite to mark the one that was posted first as the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
 let lg : {name: string};   
 for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
       lg = {
        name: list[i]
      };
      arr.push(lg);
 }
```